# alternative to get request body in node js without express

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am building an API without `express`, is there any other alternative to get a body request without using: `req.on('data',(chunk)=>{})`

Comment: No, there isn't an alternative.  The response arrives in a stream and someone has to read the stream and this is how you read a stream.  You could get some library that reads the stream for you, but someone is going to have to read the stream this way.

Answer (score 1):

Request sent to the backend is a Readable Stream, So you need to use the `EventEmitter` API to read the data off this stream.

```
    let body = '';
    req.on('data', buffer => {
        body += buffer.toString(); // convert Buffer to string
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        console.log(body);
        res.end('ok');
    });
```

And then you will have your body as a URL-encoded string.

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that the OP is asking for an option OTHER than this.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will return a string value.

```
const body = [];

req.on("data", chunk => {
body.push(chunk);
});

req.on("end", () => {
  // converts buffer stream into readable string format
  let parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString(); //
  res.send(parsedBody);
});
```

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that the OP is asking for an option OTHER than this.